# Angular Firebase Firestore añadir nuevos campos a coleccion de usuarios

Tags: nodejs, angular, firebase, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

soy nuevo con Angular y estoy teniendo un problema que creo es simple...

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion para cupones de descuento, tengo un registro con Firebase, y tengo en mi codigo para que al registrarse se guarde la informacion a su vez en FireStore, en una collecion llamada "users", donde guardo "email", "id" y "Roles" ( que de ese modo tengo diferentes roles ),

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 el caso es que quiero agregar mas campos dentro de esta coleccion, ejemplo: "telefono", encontre un modo de agregar informacion, pero solo tipo (boolean), y no se como pasarlo a (string), ya que el telefono tendra un formato +99-9999+999999 y no (true or false), les muestro mi codgio.

**apiservice.ts**

```
export class ApiService{

constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) { }

estadoChange: boolean;

}


updateEstado(key){
  this.afs.doc('users/' + key).update({
    estado : this.estadoChange = !this.estadoChange
  })
}
```

**private-component.ts**

```
actualizarEstado(key) {
    this.afs.updateEstado(key);
  }
```

**private-component.html**

```
<input type="text" (change)="actualizarEstado(user.id)">
```

Con esto agrego un nuevo campo a la coleccion de el usuario que intenta agregar la informacion,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quiero agregarlo como string, y no boolean, espero puedan ayudarme, saludos!

Comment: es raro y no entiendo bien que estas haciendo, pues el va a registrar el valor de acuerdo a lo que envíes, lo he usado un tiempo y no he tenido problemas

Comment: Hola Carlos, quiero un codigo que me sirva para agregar el valor que yo escriba en el imput, osea de tipo string, y no de tipo boolean como lo tengo ahi, esta quizas es la linea que no se cambiar.         celular : this.estadoChange = !this.estadoChange ,. cuando escribo solo obtengo true o false, sin importar que escriba en el imput

Comment: ok,  el asunto es que la funcion que tienes allí, envía es un booleano y solo actualiza el campo que alli indicas que es `estado`, ahora bien si envías un string en la function ``actualizaEstado`` este enviara la info, en todo caso podrías ayudarte con un select que indique que campo de firebase quieres actualizar y enviarle el valor desde el imput

Comment: recuerda que la function `updateEstado` es la que esta realizando el update de los datos del usuario, es alli donde debes agregar los campos a actualizar

Comment: Gracias Carlos, si entiendo lo que me dices, pero soy novato, y no tengo idea de como quedaria el codigo para ue no envie un booleano

Answer (score 0):

No trabajo con angular, pero voy a intentar traducir lo que veo a lo que quiero decirte, pruebas y nos dices si te funciona:

En tu input algo así:

```
<input type="text" (change)="actualizarEstado(user.id,this.value)">
```

NOTA: No se si existe this.value en angular, en todo caso, pasa la id del usuario y el valor del campo.

en tu component

```
    actualizarEstado(key,value) {
    this.afs.updateEstado(key,value);
  }
```

por último en tu apiservices:

```
updateEstado(key,value){
  this.afs.doc('users/' + key).update({
    campo : value
  })
}
```

El campo es el **campo** que quieres actualizar de la base de datos y el **value** el valor que quieres enviar.

De esa manera le estas pasando a la funcion de update el id del usuario y el valor del input para que este sea agregado o actualizado. Por otro lado, debes tomar en cuenta lo que te comente de agregar un select para indicar que campo de la DB quieres actualizar y pasarlo a la función también.

Prueba así y parte de allí para modificar tu integración.

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta Carlos, obtengo este error en consola,<ERROR FirebaseError: "Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field campo)">   intente definir (campo), como observable de la interface de usuario, o como string, y nada, que podra ser

Comment: es porque el valor esta llegando vacío a la funcion que realiza el update, verifica que el valor este llegando antes de pasarlo a firebase, ojo, recuerda que la palabra campo es referencial